# db2 sql unexpected token end of statement

Tags: plsql, db2

I am not very experienced in db2 sql but I am building some script which is returning me error.
I am using flyway.

This is my script:

```
SET SCHEMA my_schema;

BEGIN
  FOR c1 AS
    SELECT 'DROP user mapping for public server"' || s.servername || '"' AS cmd
      FROM syscat.servers s
    JOIN (VALUES 'DB', 'ST', 'HST', 'WDB', 'TDB') v (servername)
      ON v.servername = s.servername
    DO
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c1.cmd;
    END FOR;
END;
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "UTE IMMEDIATE c1.cmd".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.1301

[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END FOR".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.1301

[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.1301
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

This is frequently asked...

When scripting in Db2, it is necessary to tell the tool (that submits the SQL) how to distinguish between the end of a statement (default ; ), or the end of a block. A block contains multple statements.

In your script you have an anonymous block, between BEGIN and END. So you need to delimit the end of the block with a different character than ; .  Many people use the @ symbol although other characters are also allowed.

**Important note:**  Both the tool and the target Db2-server platform has to support anonymous blocks for this to work. Not every tool has this flexibility, and some Db2-server platforms do **not** support anonymous blocks.   So you need to be aware of your toolset and platform limitations.

You need to same technique if the script contains a routine (function, procedure etc), or a trigger etc - to indicate the end of a block.

The way that you configure the tool that submits the SQL varies with the tool, and your question does not say which tool you use to submit the SQL.  In a comment, you indicate flyway, so your question should read "how do I configure an alternate statement delimiter in flyway", for which other answers exist, so do your research.

For example, if you submit your script via the `db2` command line processor (at the operating system command line shell), or if you can configure you tool to shell out to the operating-system to run scripts,  **then**  you can include `--#SET TERMINATOR @` inside your script, or use the `-td@` command-line flag.  This `--#SET...` can appear multiple times inside a script if required, using different delimiters if neeed. You then use BEGIN...END@ for the block, and any subsequent statements would be terminated with the @ (instead of @) until and unless you change the terminator again inside the script.

If you submit the SQL via some GUI tool, then the GUI will have a setting somewhere to configure an "alternate statement delimiter", so you should google for that.

Comment: I am using flyway., ANy thoughts?